# Escaping a parenthesis in Powershell -Replace parameter not working

Tags: powershell, rename, escape-characters

I want to rename files from this:

`Howard -((TV) )RED HEADED LEAGUE.mp4`

to this:

`Howard - (TV) RED HEADED LEAGUE.mp4`

Since the -Replace Powershell command uses regex regular expressions, I did this to rename the files:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\(\(TV\) \)',' \(TV\) '}
```

But, outputs this error:

> Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name.

And escaping the parenthesis with back ticks, as google suggests, outputs no errors but no files are renamed:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '`(`(TV`) `)',' `(TV`) '}
```

How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your post and give an example filename with a before and after, so we can understand what the goal is that you want to achieve?

Comment: @LPChip I've edited the post. Please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\(\(TV\) \)',' (TV) '}
```

It works because the first parameter (search parameter) `'\(\(TV\) \)'` has to be a regex regular expression. So, a parenthesis needs an escape character.

But, the second parameter (substitution parameter) `' (TV) '` is treated as a plain text string, not a regex regular expression. So, no need to escape a parenthesis, with the exception of perhaps a single quote for example.

Answer (score 1):

here are two ways to do the job. [*grin*] if you have a vast number of such replacements, the regex version is likely faster.

the 1st uses regex to replace the target pattern with the substitution pattern. the target pattern has regex escapes applied as needed using the built in `[regex]::Escape()` method.

the 2nd uses the string `.Replace()` method to replace the `((` with `(` and the `) )` with `)`.

```
$InString = 'asf ((tv) ) qwe'

$Target = '((tv) )'
$Subst = ' (tv) '

$InString -replace [regex]::Escape($Target), $Subst
$InString.Replace('((', ' (').Replace(') )', ') ')
```

output ...

```
asf  (tv)  qwe
asf  (tv)  qwe
```

Comment: Nice! This may come in handy later. Thanks!

Comment: @Helix - you are most welcome! glad to help a little bit ... [*grin*]